# I don't understand how to keep the same relative size of all the elements when resizing the window

Tags: python-3.x, kivy, kivy-language

When the application is windowed the button and labels are in the right places, exactly where I want them, but when I view the window in full screen everything moves out of place

I've tried messing around with the padding and height of the box layouts and label properties, but I just getting the broken outcome.

*.py

```
import kivy
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.uix.image import Image


class LoginReg(BoxLayout):
    pass


class LoginApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return LoginReg()

if __name__== '__main__':
    LoginApp().run()
```

*.kv

```
#:kivy 1.0
#:import hex kivy.utils.get_color_from_hex
<TextInput>:
    size_hint_y: None
    height:30
<Label>:
    size_hint_y: None
    height:30
    color: 0,0,0,1
<FlatButton@ButtonBehavior+Label>:
    font_size: 18
<LoginReg>:
    id: main_win
    orientation: "vertical"
    spacing: 10
    space_x: self.size[0]/3
    space_y: 40
#Code for background start
    BoxLayout:
        id: background
        orientation: 'vertical'
        canvas.before:
            Color:
                rgba: hex('#f2f2f2f2')
            Rectangle:
                size: self.size
                pos: self.pos
        BoxLayout:
            id: header
            size_hint_y:None
            height: 50
            canvas.before:
                Color:
                    rgba: hex('#1A5276')
                Rectangle:
                    size: self.size
                    pos: self.pos
            FlatButton:
                text:"Virtual Assistant"
                color: (1,1,1,1)
        BoxLayout:
            orientation: 'vertical'
            padding: main_win.space_x, main_win.space_y
            BoxLayout:
                spacing: 10
                orientation: 'vertical'
                padding: 50
                canvas.before:
                    Color:
                        rgba: hex('#111')
                    Rectangle:
                        size: self.size
                        pos: self.pos
                Label:
                    text: "Login: "
                TextInput:
                    hint_text: "Username"
                    multiline: False
                Label:
                    text: "Password: "
                TextInput:
                    hint_text: "password"
                    multiline: False
                Button:
                    text:"Login"
                    size_hint_y: None
                    height: 60
                    background_color: (2.08, 2.40, 1.92,1)
        Label:
            id:sp
            size_hint_y:None
            height: 200
```

I am not getting any error messages, I just want to work out how to keep everything relative it its size when resizing the window.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best way to get everything to keep relative size/position is to use hints. Use `size_hint` for sizes and `pos_hint` for positions. Also, don't add unnecessary complexity to your layout. In your posted code, your `LoginReg` is a `BoxLayout`, and the only item you have in it is another `BoxLayout`. Similarly, later in your `kv` you have another vertical `BoxLayout` with its only child being another vertical `BoxLayout`. That is unnecessary complexity. Here is a simpler version of your code that I believe accomplished what you want:

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.floatlayout import FloatLayout


class LoginReg(FloatLayout):
    pass


Builder.load_string('''
#:kivy 1.0
#:import hex kivy.utils.get_color_from_hex
<TextInput>:
    size_hint_y: None
    height:30
<Label>:
    size_hint_y: None
    height:30
    color: 0,0,0,1
<FlatButton@ButtonBehavior+Label>:
    font_size: 18
<LoginReg>:
    spacing: 10
    #Code for background start
    canvas.before:
        Color:
            rgba: hex('#f2f2f2f2')
        Rectangle:
            size: self.size
            pos: self.pos
    FlatButton:
        id: fb
        canvas.before:
            Color:
                rgba: hex('#1A5276')
            Rectangle:
                size: self.size
                pos: self.pos
        pos_hint: {'center_x': 0.5, 'top':1.0}
        size_hint_y:None
        height: 50
        text:"Virtual Assistant"
        color: (1,1,1,1)
    BoxLayout:
        spacing: 10
        orientation: 'vertical'
        padding: 50
        canvas.before:
            Color:
                rgba: hex('#111')
            Rectangle:
                size: self.size
                pos: self.pos
        pos_hint: {'center_x': 0.5, 'top': (root.height - fb.height)/root.height}
        size_hint: 0.33, None
        size_hint_min_x: 200
        height: self.minimum_height
        Label:
            text: "Login: "
        TextInput:
            id: ti
            hint_text: "Username"
            multiline: False
        Label:
            text: "Password: "
        TextInput:
            hint_text: "password"
            multiline: False
        Button:
            text:"Login"
            size_hint_y: None
            height: 60
            background_color: (2.08, 2.40, 1.92,1)
''')


class LoginApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return LoginReg()


if __name__== '__main__':
    LoginApp().run()
```

I have used `Builder.load_string` instead of a file just for my own convenience.

The important changes are to make `LoginReg` extend `FloatLayout` just because it allows more flexibility than a `BoxLayout`. I have removed any `BoxLayouts` that only had a single `BoxLayout` child.

The `FlatButton` now uses `pos_hint` to position it at the top of `LoginReg`.

The `BoxLayout` inside `Loginreg` uses `pos_hint` to center it horizontally, and to position it vertically just below the `FlatButton`. It also uses `size_hint` to make its width one third of the width of `LoginReg`, but with a minimum width of `200`. Its height is set to use the minimum height that will contain its children.

Comment: Thank you so much, this is exactly what I needed. You've been a huge help.